# require vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php failed to open stream

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I uploaded my project in cpanel ..

but when i run url i hit this error.

> Warning: require(/home/**/**/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/**/**/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

i put index.php inside vendor . index code :

> require **DIR** . '/vendor/autoload.php';
>
> $app = require_once **DIR** . '/bootstrap/app.php';

Comment: Moving the index should result an error like that because the path for autoload at index.php is changed.

Did you upload also the /vendor files in your project?

Comment: yes vendor has uploaded ... i put my public direct in public_html

Comment: Yes that's expected to place the plublic folder and the rest of the files under your server public_html. Can you show the files structure?